# How can I pass query string parameters with a space char in when the callback_url is now explicit in Twitter API / Twython?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, twitter-oauth, twython, sttwitterapi

Twitter made their callback_url explicit this month.  This now creates a problem since my callback url has space chars as (+) in the parameters I pass.  It produces a 403 error.

```
qs = 'param1=value&param2=a+b'
auth = twitter.get_authentication_tokens(callback_url='http://%s/twittercallback?%s' % (host, qs))
```

The problem occurs for that plus character (+) which is a space in the form that's being retrieved;  I tried substituting "%20" but that created the same issue.

It thinks this is a separate callback url and not approved.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `'http://%s/twittercallback?%s'` be supplied with two objects to format instead of just one, `qs`?

Comment: You're right - it does and I omitted it I'll add it back to clarify.